# Unfortunately myApp has stopped while trying to override onStart

Tags: android

I am very new to android.
I am trying to study the lifecycle methods.
Tried to override the onStart method, but getting the application stopped error.
I can find that it is due to NullPointerException but I can't determine due to which variable it is.
Please help,
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView mStart;
int iStart=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mStart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sStart);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    iStart++;
    mStart.setText(iStart);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And here is the log,

```
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): Process: course.android.myfirstapp, PID: 1604
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{course.android.myfirstapp/course.android.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at course.android.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:26)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5253)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2149)
  03-08 07:08:05.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):   ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't find ID of any UI element before call

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

method. So change from

```
mStart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sStart);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mStart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sStart);
```

You have to also change this from

```
 mStart.setText(iStart);
```

to

```
  mStart.setText(iStart+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

After `setContentView()` only view is available.otherwise its `null` Change order of these lines

```
 mStart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sStart);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

into

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mStart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sStart);
```

And in this line

```
 mStart.setText(iStart);
```

here `iStart` taken as a `resource id`..so it will throw `ResourceNotFoundException`..change that line like.

```
mStart.setText(""+iStart);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` you assign `mStart` before calling `setContentView()`. So `mStart` will be `null`. You need to call `findViewById` after inflating the view using `setContentView`